# DesiredchainId API obsolete

Tags: visual-studio, api, metadata

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNqnr.png)

Can anyone recommend how I can do something here to continue on with my work? It says this API is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to resolve this. replace the deprecated line with

> networks

. I hope this helps.